# issues associated with inner joins

Tags: sql, sqlplus

My intension is to produce a detailed report showing which clients have not dealt at all during the last 12 months and their last dealing date.

```
select client.client_code,client.client_name,dealing_record.transaction_number,
transaction_type.transaction,dealing_record.deal_date
FROM client INNER JOIN dealing_record ON client.client_id=dealing_record.client_id
            INNER JOIN Transaction_type ON    
        transaction_type.transaction_type_id=dealing_record.transaction_type_id
 WHERE deal_date NOT BETWEEN to_date('07-Nov-2012') AND SYSDATE;
```

the above sql codes produces

```
CLIENT_COD CLIENT_NAME          TRANSA TRANS DEAL_DATE
---------- -------------------- ------ ----- ---------
C001       David clare          D02    Sell  20-FEB-10
C002       James love           D03    Buy   05-MAY-11
C004       Jame lee             D05    Buy   05-JAN-12
C005       Kay Ade              D07    Buy   05-DEC-11
```

the above results happens to show all i wanted but with a little problem. all the clients have not dealt within the last 12 months but david clare has both dealt during the 12 months and before.. the aim is to show those who have never dealt in the last 12month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT c.client_code,
  c.client_name,
  dr.transaction_number,
  tt.TRANSACTION,
  dr.deal_date
FROM client
INNER JOIN dealing_record dr ON c.client_id = dr.client_id
INNER JOIN Transaction_type tt ON tt.transaction_type_id = dr.transaction_type_id
WHERE c.client_id NOT IN (
    SELECT client_id
    FROM dealing_record
    WHERE deal_date > '07-Nov-2012'
    );
```

This will exclude the client_id's that have a deal_date after `'07-Nov-2012'`